# Why would a duped table be half the size?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I duplicated a large table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```

I checked rows afterwards like this:

```
select count(*) from oldtable;
select count(*) from newtable;
```

to make sure they had the same # of rows

However in Navicat (whose counts I don't trust) the Data Length seemed way off so I ran a query on size like this:

```
SELECT 
    table_name AS `Table`, 
    round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "$MY_DB"
    AND table_name = "#MY_TABLE"
```

And the duped table is indeed almost 1/2 the size. I know for now that is some sparse information but I am wondering now if either:

1. There was some error in the duplication (spot checking indicates no)
2. Duplicating in that way somehow optimize(d)(s) the data/indexes

Comment: This is on an InnoDB table? I'm guessing this is because the new table has a clean index, with no prior deletions. `OPTIMIZE TABLE oldtable` may reduce the size.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes it is innodb. I thought it might be something like that. A large query is running on the oldtable but when done I will run the optimize on it and report back and update Q here for future reference.

Comment: I'll put in a proper answer below with links to documentation. I just tested the same myself on a large table.

Comment: Though it worth noting that, unless the row format is fixed, MyISAM tables can exhibit such gaps too.

Comment: @user3649739 Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes and just marked your answer. Indeed my duplicating the table turns out to be pretty much exactly what InnoDb does when you ask it to optimize. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: Ah, good. Glad to hear it's sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an InnoDB table, over time the index will accumulate something similar to hard disk fragmentation, where `INSERT` and `DELETE` operations leave space in the index file that is not made available for reuse by the operating system.

By duplicating the table via `INSERT INTO...SELECT *...`, the new table is essentially getting a cleaner index with less of the fragmentation the old one had.  You can reclaim that space on the old table by [running an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html).

> Use OPTIMIZE TABLE in these cases, depending on the type of table:
>
> After doing substantial insert, update, or delete operations on an InnoDB table that has its own .ibd file because it was created with the innodb_file_per_table option enabled. The table and indexes are reorganized, and disk space can be reclaimed for use by the operating system.

So in your environment:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE oldtable
```

Afterward, check the `index_length` in `information_schema.TABLES` again and its size will likely be closer to that of the duplicated table.

Note: On a large table this may take a long time, so you should not attempt it when locking will be an issue. For InnoDB, MySQL may actually drop and recreate the table rather than optimize the existing index in place.

Addendum after some tests:

Even when duplicating a large table in my testing, though the new table's `index_length` was considerably smaller than the old one, it still had space that could be reclaimed with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`. After optimizing the newly duplicated table, (with no intervening inserts/deletions) both old and new had identical sizes.